# Creating a typescript library for generic functionality in several projects

Tags: typescript, webpack, module, namespaces

I want to export several classes ,some are standalone and some require each other, wrapped by one namespace, as a module for other projects to use.

So I setup a webpack build to compile them into one minified .js file and one .d.ts file, and they are all wrapped by the namespace "Platform".

Here is an example class I use for custom events:

```
namespace Platform {
    export class GameEvent {
        ****code****
    }
}
```

the problem is, that once I wrapped them in this namespace, the build fails with this error:

> ERROR in ./Utilities/GameEvent.ts
> Module build failed (from ../node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
> Error: TypeScript emitted no output for \Platform\src\Utilities\GameEvent.ts.
> at makeSourceMapAndFinish (\Platform\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:53:18)
> at successLoader (\Platform\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:40:5)
> at Object.loader (\Platform\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:23:5)

here is my tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "esnext",
        "strict": true,
        "noEmit": false,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "outDir": "./types",
        "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ],
        "removeComments": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types",
            "node_module/phaser/types"
        ],
        "types": [
            "phaser",
            "jest"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*",
    ]
}
```

here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const DeclarationBundlerPlugin = require('declaration-bundler');
const fs = require('fs');

const srcDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const typesDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'types');

function scanDirectory(dir) {
  const fileArr = [];

  fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach((file) => {
    const filepath = path.join(dir, file);
    if (fs.lstatSync(filepath).isDirectory()) {
      fileArr.push(...scanDirectory(filepath));
    } else if (/\.tsx?$/.test(file)) {
      fileArr.push(path.resolve(filepath));
    }
  });

  return fileArr;
}

const entryPoints = scanDirectory(srcDir);
const typeEntryPoints = scanDirectory(typesDir);

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: {
    'platform': entryPoints
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: "[name].min.js",
  },
  externals: {
    phaser: 'phaser',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
          },
        ],
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'typeof SHADER_REQUIRE': JSON.stringify(false),
      'typeof CANVAS_RENDERER': JSON.stringify(true),
      'typeof WEBGL_RENDERER': JSON.stringify(true)
    }),
    new DeclarationBundlerPlugin({
      entry: typeEntryPoints,
      moduleName: 'Platform',
      out: './platform.d.ts',
    }),
  ],
  performance: { hints: false },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          compress: true,
          safari10: true,
          mangle: true,
          output: {
            comments: false
          }
        }
      })
    ]
  }
};
```

and these are my devDependencies:

```
"@jest/globals": "^29.3.1",
    "@declaration-bundler": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.5",
    "before-build-webpack": "^0.2.13",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "glob": "^8.0.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "^2.4.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.3.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.6",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.18",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "webpack": "^5.28.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
```

I tried just using "export default class" for each file without the namespace, but then when I publish the package and use it in another project, it fails to recognize it as a module and fails to build/test.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, not completely how I would like but its working well.

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```js
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const DtsBundleWebpack = require("dts-bundle-webpack");
const removeEmptyDirectories = require('remove-empty-directories');

const libPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib');

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: {
    'platform': "./platform.ts"
  },
  output: {
    path: libPath,
    filename: "[name].min.js",
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'typeof SHADER_REQUIRE': JSON.stringify(false),
      'typeof CANVAS_RENDERER': JSON.stringify(true),
      'typeof WEBGL_RENDERER': JSON.stringify(true)
    }),
    new DtsBundleWebpack({
      name: "<lib name>",
      main: "lib/platform.d.ts",
      out: "platform.d.ts",
      removeSource: true,
      outputAsModuleFolder: true
    }),
    function () {
      this.hooks.done.tap("Done", (stats) => {
        removeEmptyDirectories(libPath);
      });
    }
  ],
  performance: { hints: false },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          compress: true,
          safari10: true,
          mangle: true,
          output: {
            comments: false
          }
        }
      })
    ]
  }
};
```

My file structure is like so:

[file structure src/ folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dyI4.png)

where each index.ts file has an "export * from 'filename'" for each of the class files.

and the platform.ts file exports all of the modules

Comment: My only issue remaining is I wanted all of my modules to somehow be wrapped by one module, like Phaser is structured, So every object is called from my main module.
(Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite for example)

Answer (score 0):

Another gotcha here, probably not your problem in this example, but another common cause of `Error: TypeScript emitted no output for _____.ts` is that `noEmit` is set to true in `tsconfig.json`.